# No power to isolator switch

Tags: electrical, hvac

I recently moved into a repossessed flat and the electrics were a bit of a mess. Sockets, switches, etc. hanging off walls but it has since all been made safe/good by an electrician.

The only thing still not working is the extraction system. There are ducting hoses that run from both the kitchen and the bathroom ceilings back to a large metal box above the ceiling of the utility cupboard. I am assuming that this is an extraction unit which pulls the air out of the kitchen and bathroom and then pushes it outside.
On the outside wall of the utility cupboard is an isolator switch which I am confident controls it - it is the only one in the flat and my neighbours uses this switch to turn theirs on/off.

However, there doesn't seem to be any power going to the switch. When I check it with a multimeter I am reading between 0-5V depending on what circuit breakers I have switched on.

I was advised to cut a hole in the ceiling and examine the extraction unit to see why it's not working, but before I do this and make a mess, I am inclined to try and figure out why there is no power to the switch first. Logically to me, if there is no power to the switch, then it's obvious the extraction unit isn't going to work, so it would make more sense to figure out why it has no power.

What I am wondering is what is the best way to figure this out? I am assuming that it runs off the light circuit and that there is a break in the circuit somewhere, but the lights all work fine. I'm thinking it's possible there is just a loose cable somewhere behind a light switch that is breaking the isolator circuit, but short of unscrewing them all to look, is there a better option that would speed this up? Some tool that will help me better work out where the fault is?

Comment: Is power run to the isolation switch first, or to the fan first with the switch on a loop?

Comment: You know, obDisclosure here, the law most places says that a renter or landlord cannot do their own electrical work in a rental unit.  It must be done by a licensed electrician.  Troubleshooting and tracing is fair game, as long as you leave it alone.

Comment: So in the other units, is the extraction system on its own breaker, or does it share a same breaker with certain other loads?  Presuming this unit was wired the same, were the other loads disturbed?  Was one of them taken out of service for some reason?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm not 100% certain since the cabling is hidden from view in the ceiling, that's something I would like to work out but not sure how.

But I would assume power is not run to the isolation switch first as there is obviously no power when I read it with a multimeter and because this area is one of the few parts of the flat that seemed untouched when I moved in. I am inclined to think that if it was coming directly off the fuse box it would still be working.

Comment: @Harper Yep, I have no intention of touching/doing anything other than something simple such as removing a light switch or socket in order to see if there is a loose cabling.

Comment: @Harper I'm not 100% certain how the other units work - only that this isolator switch was the one controlling their extraction system leading me to believe it does the same for mine. Since there are no remaining breakers in my fusebox to turn on (all of them are on) and none of the labelling on the fusebox references the extraction system, and also because my neighbours turns on/off when lights are turned on/off I am inclined to think it shares a circuit with lighting.